# How to use sublime text vars in snippets?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext-snippet

I am trying to create snippet where must be displayed the name of the current file

I tried to do this:

```
<content><![CDATA[Hello, this is a $file_name]]></content>
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I did it like this:

```
<content><![CDATA[Hello, this is a $TM_FILENAME]]></content>
```